# How to find all numbers in a list that are not part of a pair - using python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a python 3 function that finds all numbers in a list (unspecified length) that are not part of a pair.

For example, given the list `[1, 2, 1, 3, 2]`, the function will return 3; and given the list `[0, 1, 1, 7, 8, 3, 9, 3, 9]`, the function will return 0, 7, and 8.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not use the well-defined method for counting elements and then only output the items that have a count of 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function :

```
>>> def find(l):
...   return (i for i in l if l.count(i)==1)

>>> l= [0, 1, 1, 7, 8, 3, 9, 3, 9]
>>> list(find(l))
[0, 7, 8]
```

This function will return a generator that is contain the elements in list which those count is equal to 1.

Comment: Could you try and make this less efficient? :p

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how I would do it. What does it mean a "pair"?
You should say, find all the numbers repeated oddly in the array.

First plan: (more efficient!)
Sort the list and then a single loop through your list should be enough to find how many numbers of each there are inside and you can generate awhile another list that you will return.

Second plan (nicer in python, but also more expensive because of the number of evaluations though the hole list):
Try the solution of Kasra. 'count' function from 'list' type helps our code but not our efficiency. It counts the number of times that appears the value 'i' on the list 'l', obviously.

If the pair need to be "closed pair" I mean, if you have three 1 (ones), do you have one pair and one single 1? or do you have all the 1 paired? If the second one, the solution of Kasra is Ok. Else you should compare:

```
if l.count(i) % 2 == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily and efficiently done in 3 lines with collections.Counter.

```
from collections import Counter

def unpaired(numbers):
    for key, count in Counter(numbers).items():
        if count % 2:
            yield key

print(list(unpaired([1, 2, 1, 3, 2])))
# [3]
print(list(unpaired([0, 1, 1, 7, 8, 3, 9, 3, 9])))
# [0, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer comport if you have three equals numbers or if you have one pair and one single number without pair.

```
def name(array):
o = sorted(array)
c = []
d = []
for i in o:
    if o.count(i) % 2 == 1:
        c.append(i)
        for j in c:
            if j not in d:
                d.append(j)
return d
```

or do not use for `j` in `c` and use directly:

```
return list(set(c))
```

for example:

```
array = [0, 1, 1, 7, 8, 3, 9, 3, 9, 9]
output: [0, 7, 8, 9]
```